# Restlet JAX-RS deserializes into ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>

Tags: jax-rs, deserialization, restlet

I started using the Restlet JAX-RS extension, but I'm finding that lists get deserialized into an `ArrayList` of `LinkedHashMap` instead of the class.

```
@Path("MyService")
public class MyService {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("myTestMethod")
    public String testIt(final List<MyTestClass> myList) {
        return "hello";
    }
}

public class MyTestClass {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
}
```

Any ideas on how to have Jackson deserialize into `List<MyTestClass>`?  It works fine when I don't use the JAX-RS extension, but I need this to port over some existing web services.

Thanks for any help.

==Update==

Sending data like this:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://localhost:8182/MyService/myTestMethod"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

request_object = [{"name": "joe"}, {"name": "bill"}]

params = json.dumps(request_object)

response = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I should also mention that if I change the method's parameter from `List<MyTestClass>` to just `MyTestClass`, it does get properly deserialized into `MyTestClass`.

Comment: What data are you sending in the POST request?

Comment: @GeorgHenkel Just updated post to show Python example calling the service.

Comment: @RedTailedHawk what is your question ??? *lists get deserialized into an ArrayList of LinkedHashMap instead of the class* Are you referring `[{"name": "joe"}, {"name": "bill"}]` ?

Comment: @Ravi Right.  Any ideas on how to have Jackson deserialize into `List<MyTestClass>`?

Comment: @RedTailedHawk No, I'm still not clear. what is your expectation ???

Comment: @Ravi That the `myList` parameter is a `List<MyTestClass>` at runtime instead of `List<LinkedHashMap>`.

Comment: @RedTailedHawk I'm still not clear what are you trying to say.. what do you mean by runtime ??  You can change the code accordingly ?

Comment: @Ravi he means that because of type erasure, at runtime the list is oftype LinkedHashMap, and he can not get MyTestClass objects from it

Comment: @RedTailedHawk I think you need to do something with GenericEntity, I'm not sure, but I will do some research and let you know

Comment: BTW, it works fine with Jersey / Glassfish / Grizzly, so seems to point to a Restlet JAX-RS bug.

Comment: @RedTailedHawk oh, then in that case I don't know what you can do. Maybe file a bug report with Restlet? Just curious, but why did you choose Restlet over Jersey/RESTEasy?

Comment: I reported it on their Issues page.